# Accessing Javascript variables with OLE Automation

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, com, autohotkey, ole

## The Problem

I'm currently creating an application to automate a web application. To write this program I am using OLE automation (COM). One of the annoying parts of the website is, that when it is retrieving data the JavaScript hangs. To try and detect when the JavaScript engine is able to be used again I am trying to set and then read a variable. See my code below:

```
IE := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible := 1
IE.Navigate("about:blank")
sleep,1000
javascript =
(
console.log('testing foo')
var foo = "hello"
alert(foo)
)


TryTillPass(IE,javascript)

RunJS(COM,javascript){
    js := javascript . ";"
    js := StrReplace(js,"`r",";") 
    js := StrReplace(js,"`n",";") 
    js := StrReplace(js,";;",";") 

    COM.Navigate("javascript:" js)
}

TryTillPass(COM,javascript){
    x := COM.Name
    Msgbox, %x%
Test:
    Try {
        RunJS(COM,javascript)
        jvar := COM.document.parentWindow.foo
        console.log(foo)
    } Catch e {
        msgbox, Error:%e%
        Sleep,1000
        GoTo Test
    }

    return jvar
}
```

The thing that confuses me is that whenever I run `COM.document.parentWindow.foo` I get the error `Unknown name`. To try to overcome this I catch the error and try again (since I assume this is when the JavaScript engine is hanging...).

However the `console.log(foo)` runs fine... So this implies that the JSEngine isn't hanging...

**Ultimately I've got very stuck. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?**

Comment: I have no idea how to do this with Auto HotKey, I would look into hooking in to the events generated by the control. Here is an [example in Perl](http://perltricks.com/article/139/2014/12/11/Automated-Internet-Explorer-screenshots-using-Win32--OLE/).

Comment: Wow... Perl is different to what I'm used to for sure  :O

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Gui, Add, ActiveX, w800 h800 vwb, Shell.Explorer
wb.Navigate("about:blank")
Gui, Show
while wb.busy
    sleep 10
window := wb.document.parentWindow
return

F1::
javascript =
(
console.log('testing foo')
var foo = "hello"
alert(foo)
)
    window.execScript(javascript)  ; This injects the code
    msgbox % window.foo     ; Access the Value in AutoHotkey
    return

GuiClose:
    ExitApp
```

Example 2:

```
IE := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible := 1
IE.Navigate("about:blank")

javascript =
(
console.log('testing foo')
var foo = "hello"
alert(foo)
)
sleep 1000

myReturnVar := IE_InjectJS(WinExist("ahk_class IEFrame"), javascript, "foo")

MsgBox % myReturnVar

return

IE_InjectJS(hWnd_MainWindow, JS_to_Inject="", VarNames_to_Return="", COM_to_Call1="", COM_to_Call2="") {

   window := _win(hWnd_MainWindow)

   wb := WBGet("ahk_id" hWnd_MainWindow)

   if COM_to Call1 
   {
    ;MsgBox, 4096,, COM_to_Call1 is: %COM_to_Call1%, 4       
    Loop, Parse, COM_to_Call1, `, 
    {
    ;MsgBox, 4096,, A_LoopField is: %A_LoopField%, 4
        wb[A_LoopField]     
    }    
   }     

   if JS_to_Inject
      window.execScript(JS_to_Inject)

   if VarNames_to_Return
      Loop, Parse, VarNames_to_Return, `,
      {
         Loop, Parse, A_LoopField, .
            result := (A_Index=1? window:result)[A_LoopField]
         Ret .= result ","
      }

   if COM_to_Call2 
   {
    ;MsgBox, 4096,, COM_to_Call2 is: %COM_to_Call2%, 4                 
    Loop, Parse, COM_to_Call2, `, 
    {
    ;MsgBox, 4096,, A_LoopField is: %A_LoopField%, 4
    wb[A_LoopField]     
    }               
   }  

   return SubStr(Ret,1,-1)
}

_win(hwnd, Svr#=1) {               ;// based on ComObjQuery docs

   static msg := DllCall("RegisterWindowMessage", "str", "WM_HTML_GETOBJECT")
        , IID1 := "{0002DF05-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"  ; IID_IWebBrowserApp
        , IID2 := "{332C4427-26CB-11D0-B483-00C04FD90119}"  ; IID_IHTMLWindow2

   SendMessage msg, 0, 0, Internet Explorer_Server1, ahk_id %hwnd%

   if (ErrorLevel != "FAIL") {

      lResult:=ErrorLevel, VarSetCapacity(GUID,16,0)

      if DllCall("ole32\CLSIDFromString", "wstr","{332C4425-26CB-11D0-B483-00C04FD90119}", "ptr",&GUID) >= 0 {

         DllCall("oleacc\ObjectFromLresult", "ptr",lResult, "ptr",&GUID, "ptr",0, "ptr*",pdoc)

            return  ComObj(9,ComObjQuery(pwb:=ComObjQuery(pdoc,IID1,IID1),IID2,IID2),1)
                ,   ObjRelease(pdoc), ObjRelease(pwb)

      }

   }

}

WBGet(WinTitle="ahk_class IEFrame", Svr#=1) {               ;// based on ComObjQuery docs
   static msg := DllCall("RegisterWindowMessage", "str", "WM_HTML_GETOBJECT")
        , IID := "{0002DF05-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"   ;// IID_IWebBrowserApp
;//     , IID := "{332C4427-26CB-11D0-B483-00C04FD90119}"   ;// IID_IHTMLWindow2
   SendMessage msg, 0, 0, Internet Explorer_Server%Svr#%, %WinTitle%
   if (ErrorLevel != "FAIL") {
      lResult:=ErrorLevel, VarSetCapacity(GUID,16,0)
      if DllCall("ole32\CLSIDFromString", "wstr","{332C4425-26CB-11D0-B483-00C04FD90119}", "ptr",&GUID) >= 0 {
         DllCall("oleacc\ObjectFromLresult", "ptr",lResult, "ptr",&GUID, "ptr",0, "ptr*",pdoc)
         return ComObj(9,ComObjQuery(pdoc,IID,IID),1), ObjRelease(pdoc)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Drat. Well as much as I would like to use ActiveX windows, I'm not able to sadly. When I do, I login to our site and run a report it asks me again to login and do the whole process again!

Comment: So I take it the second example didn't work for you? If it did please mark this as answered so others can find and benefit from this.

Comment: Oh I see, I never checked the 2nd example. At home I don't have a windows pc to test it :p I'll check it out tomorrow! Inject JS is probably the way forward! :)

Comment: Awesome, hope it works for you, worked great in my tests.

Comment: This code is much more reliable than IE.Navigate() no idea why, but often with IE.Navigate() I get the error 'Navigate is already in use'... Sadly my idea to solve the issue I was having was flawed due to me misunderstanding how JavaScript is executed in browsers. But thanks for all the code! :D Will be using this at a later date when I am not automating this specific website... xD